# Messages alike UiTextView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

Im trying to make messages alike TextField which is one line tall and its maximum height is 5 lines. When user reaches its maximum height (5 lines), scrolling will be enabled and TextField will stop its height expansion.

I have this piece of code, which is doing height expansion on each newline, but does not stop, when user reaches 5 lines height and does not enable scrolling:

```
struct AutoAdjustingTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
@Binding var text: String

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    textView.delegate = context.coordinator
    textView.textContainerInset = .zero
    textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    textView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
    return textView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    uiView.text = text
    updateTextViewHeight(uiView)
}

private func updateTextViewHeight(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.frame.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    if textView.frame.size.height != size.height {
        textView.frame.size.height = size.height
    }
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
    var parent: AutoAdjustingTextView

    init(_ parent: AutoAdjustingTextView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        parent.text = textView.text
        parent.updateTextViewHeight(textView)
    }
}
```

}

**Im running on IOS 14**

Answer (score 1):

In your updateTextViewHeight(_:) method, you're setting the textView's height to match the size that fits its content. However, you're not putting any limit on the height. This causes the textView to grow indefinitely as the user keeps entering new lines of text.

To limit the textView's height to a maximum of 5 lines, you need to calculate the height of 5 lines and restrict the textView's height to that maximum. You can enable scrolling when the textView's content height exceeds this maximum.

You can achieve this by modifying your updateTextViewHeight(_:) method as follows:

```
    private func updateTextViewHeight(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.frame.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    // Calculate max height for 5 lines
    let maxHeight = textView.font!.lineHeight * 5

    // Limit textView height and enable scrolling when content exceeds max height
    if size.height > maxHeight {
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        if textView.frame.size.height != maxHeight {
            textView.frame.size.height = maxHeight
        }
    } else {
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        if textView.frame.size.height != size.height {
            textView.frame.size.height = size.height
        }
    }
}
```

This modification calculates the maximum height for 5 lines (textView.font!.lineHeight * 5) and sets the textView's height to the smaller of size.height (the height that fits its content) and maxHeight. It enables scrolling when the content height exceeds maxHeight.

Comment: Now when I use your code, it works properly, but simultaneously I ran into another issue when I set the maximum height, there is the weird redundant border above the text field. Is there a way to set the maximum height without having the border?